# Hwo can i emit Flask-SocketIO messages outside of socketio context?

Tags: flask-socketio

A emitted message from my python flask webserver (flask socketio server) does not arrive at the javascript socketio client.

Within a socketio context everything works fine.

I already read all the topics here about that problem... so i included the monkey.patch, tried eventlet as async_mode and added some other hints, so i got the following codebase now:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "zISMDCwvfJY2TXHMKHrB" 
sio = SocketIO(app, async_mode='eventlet')
eventlet.monkey_patch()

@app.route('/index')
def index():
    someotherfunction()
    return render_template('index.html')

@sio.event
def my_event(message):
    print(message)

@sio.event
def hello(message):
    sio.emit('hello', {'data': 'got it!'})
    print(message)

def someotherfunction():
    with app.app_context():
        sio.emit('hello', {'data': 'got it123123!'}, namespace='/')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sio.run(app, host="localhost", port="8080", debug=True)
```

and here the socketio client side segment:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        var socket = io();
        socket.on('connect', function()
        {
            socket.emit('my_event', {data: 'I\'m connected!'});
        });
        socket.on('hello', function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
        });
    </script>
```

So the 'hello' function will emit the data successfully after request, but someotherfunction() will not emit any data to the client side.